# Is there Any way that the HREF can popup this?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When this code pops up as a form it works well, but when I press "Don't have an Account.." it redirects to the Parent Directory.

Can someone help?

```js
document.querySelector("#linkCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
  createAccountForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="headerList">
    <li id="item"> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="item"> <a href="about-us.html">About us</a></li>
    <li id="item"> <a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a></li>
    <li id="popup-login">
      <button onclick="togglePopup()">Login/Register</button>
      <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
          <form class="form" id="login">
            <h1 class="form__title">Login/Register</h1>
            <div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username or email">
              <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
              <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
              <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
            <p class="form__text">
              <a href="#" class="form__link">Forgotten your password?</a>
            </p>
            <p class="form__text">
              <a class="form__link" href="./" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account?</a>
            </p>
          </form>
```

Comment: There are several ways, e.g. using Bootstrap or any of several jQuery plugins. The modifications ought to be done in the href, but also in the code generating the current popup, which you did not include.

Comment: Im a beginner so this is all I did write in JS code: document.querySelector("#linkCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
        createAccountForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");

    });

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS and framework code. Don't post code in comments

Comment: There is no `createAccountForm` nor `loginForm` anywhere in the code. Also no togglePopup

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why is this question tagged with PHP or CSS, but does not contain any references to them?

Comment: I tried actually keeping it as simple as it gets with just the href,but JQUERY seems to be the answer(I tagged PHP because I would accept any Answer).But I got what I needed ,so thank you guys

Comment: PHP is server side only, so that would not be relevant here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by clicking on the button you are clicking on a link `<a>` with `href="./"`.

The solution for this case should be: implementing javascript trigger instead of usual html-link:

```
<a class="form__link" href="void(0);" onclick="toggleCreateAccountPopup()" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account?</a>
```

Here, href is voided, and JS-trigger `toggleCreateAccountPopup()` is called - instead of linking to parent dir.